# query parameter is not working in mountebank URL

Tags: mountebank

I am facing issue while getting the response using the Query during the mocking data with Mountebank tool:
Below is the link which I have tired:
`GET:http://localhost:6173/entities/?key=first`

I want to get the "second" response, but what I'm getting is: "No response".

```
{
  "port": 6173,
  "protocol": "http",
  "stubs": [
    {
      "predicates": [
        {
          "equals": {
            "path": "/entities",
            "query": {
                "key":"first"
            },
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          }
        }
      ],

"responses": [
        {
          "is": {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": [
              {
                "id": "second"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "responses": [
        {
          "is": { "statusCode": 404 }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual Response: 
No response

expected response:
second

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the "equals" predicate, your request will need to match exactly what was specified. In this case, you'll also need to add the '/' character to the end of the path. Note that you will also need to make sure you are always passing the Content-Type header in each request, otherwise the stub will not respond.

To get the behaviour you are looking for, I believe your predicate will need to look like this (no changes other than the value of 'path'):

```
"predicates": [
{
  "equals": {
    "path": "/entities/",
    "query": {
        "key":"first"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
]
```